# How to get unicode value used XmlReader class in C#

Tags: c#

I have used XmlReader Class and have to Parsed font file Svg format. I could not parsed glyph
tags attribute unicode string value

```
 <svg><font><glyph unicode="&#xe600;" /></font></svg>
```

I had tried

```
 if (xmlReader.GetAttribute("unicode") != null)
 {
 string unicode = xmlReader.GetAttribute("unicode");
  }
```

Got output
**unicode**=""

I need exactly unicode string value.

Can anyone Answer please !

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the response - that's the Unicode character represented by the UTF-8 E600 hex value. This value is in the private use area which means there is no standard glyph that can be shown, so a default glyph is used.

A `char` is a 16-bit number representing a UTF16 codepoint, so you already have the codepoint. If you want to format it as a hex string you can use the `x4` format, eg:

```
char theChar=unicode.Chars[0];
string hexString=String.Format("{0:x4}",theChar);
```

This will return `E600`.

If you want to output the same string as the original you can use `"&#x{0x:4}"`

Comment: Thanks,..but used above this xmlReader.GetAttribute("unicode");  GetAttriute method return string value="".I have used your code inside xmlReader class coming same output like ..

Comment: As I said, that *is* what's stored in the XML file. Just as `&nbsp;` is the encoding of space , `&#xe600;` is the encoding of a character in the private use area that can only be represented by a placeholder, the box. A custom font can specify its own glyph for this character but Arial or Courier or whatever font you use in your editor or browser simply displays a box. What code did you try, what did you get and what do you expect to get?

Comment: fine..I want to used xmlreader.getAttributes("unicode") will get current string (hexadecimal-E600) and then get "E600" equal integer value 58880.And you said right then how can get interger value equal hexadecimal via xmlreader.getAtributes() method .

Comment: fine..I want to used xmlreader.getAttributes("unicode") will get current string (hexadecimal-E600) and then get "E600" equal integer value 58880.And you said right then how can get interger value equal hexadecimal via xmlreader.getAtributes() method ?And while XmlRead if get E600 string value than i can easy to convert integer value 58880 but string value came box("") raised issue .Did you get what except ?do you have answer pl share to me ?